# PHP - Check if a function contains

Tags: php

I want to check if a function contains a variable called `$marker`.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
if(function('head') contains '$marker') {
     return true;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why? There's no real justification for doing so? Variables ued in functions should only be relevant inside the function itself. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: The short answer is "NO". You have no reason to need such a feature, except for a poorly designed program. What exactly do you want to achieve? Whatever it is, there surely are other ("correct") ways to do it.

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm trying to block some spam coming from a plugin, I don't want to modify the plugin files itself because once they update, the spam is back.

Comment: @J. Doe Spam how? Either way, would the variable name matter? You can't possibly know what variable names are used inside a function without examining the function itself, and global scope is isolated from function scope in PHP anyway, so the variable names used on the inside won't affect the variable names used on the outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummm...  it's not built into PHP, and, frankly, changing the files would be better, but for **science reasons**, I wrote a check for it.  It fetches the filenames's contents every function call, so I'd recommend, if you use it more than once, to store the file's contents in another variable, but, nevertheless, this is will give you a functional view on how to do it:

```
<?php

function test() {   $marker;}

function negativeTest() {
    $noMarker;
}

function checkFunction($function, $variable, $filename) {
    $file = file_get_contents($filename);
    preg_match_all("/function\s+([a-z0-9_-]+)\s*\(.*?\)\s*\{((\n|.)*?)\}/im",$file,$matches);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
        if ($matches[1][$i] == $function && strpos($matches[2][$i], $variable) != false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

echo checkFunction("test","\$marker","index.php");

?>
```

Comment: I'd never ever do that

Comment: I've never thought of this programming question before, so I decided to write something that could do it.  (And, no, I wouldn't use it).

Comment: You'd probably be better working with the AST (assuming that you know the filename where the function is defined), or by using reflection (which can work with the function directly without needing to know the filename)

Comment: Cool thought, could you  post an example of how to do it in AST?